# If birthdate's are stored as type "Date" in MySQL, how would you determine if it's a user's birthday today in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

If birthdate's are stored as type "Date" in MySQL, how would you determine if it's a specific user's birthday today in PHP?

Is it simply a matter of grabbing the birthdate column value, doing on a explode on the `-`, and then checking if the day and month match the current day and month in PHP?  Or is there a simpler and less crude way of doing it?

Also, what query would you use to `SELECT` **all** users whose birthday it is today?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you'll need to exclude the year, you can use the `MONTH` and `DAY` SQL functions like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birthday) = DAY(NOW());
```

Don't forget to add an index on this column or it will seriously degrade performance as data grows.

In PHP, you can just use the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
if (date('m-d', strtotime($row['date'])) == date('m-d'))
    //-- Today is my birthday! Hooray!
```

Comment: Probably only needs some handling for the Feb 29th edge case; those people still do celebrate birthdays, even though the exact date does not occur every year.

Comment: @Ianzz - Depends; (in)famously, the Pirates of Penzanze use this to re-induct a rather conflicted crewmember (who would otherwise be considered to have fufilled his terms of indenture).  Randy - is the `&` valid in mySQL?  It's not in (my version of) DB2.

Comment: This worked for finding all users whose birthday it is today, thanks.  But how would you determine if it's a specific user's birthday today in PHP (based on their birthdate)?

Comment: @X-Zero A single ampersand is a bitwise `and`, and double ampersand can be substituted for the `AND` keyword for a logical `and` - basically identical to PHP rules and regs.

Comment: It was a typo on my end... sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Use MySQL's [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to extract the month and day from the users' birth dates, and compare them to the same values extracted from the current date:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
    DAY(birthday) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND
    MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

That makes sure the important values - month and day - match, regardless of the year.  Hope that helps!

PS: You might be tempted to use `DAYOFYEAR` as a simpler version.  Don't.  Leap years'll screw you up.

**Edit:** It looks like using date functions in your where clauses can [really slow you down](http://netfactory.dk/2004/12/13/mysql-date-functions-and-indexes/), especially in big tables.  See my last comment, below, for a bit more on that.

Comment: What is generally faster between this solution and randy's solution?

Comment: The two are effectively identical.

Comment: @Programmer - Nothing, really.  `CURDATE` only deals with the date, whereas `NOW` gives you a full date+time.  And randy uses boolean and (`&`) instead of conditional and (`AND`).  But these are severely minor differences - I doubt you'd notice and performance difference at all.  Cheers!

Comment: @XavierHolt `and randy uses boolean and (&) instead of conditional and (AND)` - Actually what he used was, presumably by mistake since it has now been altered, a *bitwise* `and`, which is a not-so-minor difference. If we're going to be correct about it (and that's what are striving for, I assume?) a `boolean and`, as you put it is in fact a *logical* `and`. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm not up on the internals of MySQL, but depending on how it queries the index, comparing month first would weed out more irrelevant records before needing to compare the day portion. I've not tested this theory though... and yes, the `&` was a mistake on my part

Comment: @DaveRandom - Absolutely correct.  It was another typo, on my part this time.  Cheers!

Comment: @randy - While attempting to do the most coarse filter first is a laudable goal, the problem is that the SQL standard doesn't guarantee the order of operations in a statement - ie, there's no short-circuiting, as in most other languages.  It's up to the optimizer whether or not it can recognize whether what order of filtering will help performance - for instance, if all dates fall within the same month, actually calling the `MONTH()` function on every row will simply waste resources, while `DAY()` would be needed for the final selection.

Comment: @randy - I'm not either, but this question intrigued me and I poked around a bit on how to set up an index for this.  It seems that [WHERE clauses with date functions in them are slow](http://netfactory.dk/2004/12/13/mysql-date-functions-and-indexes/), so the best option is probably to split the date into separate year/month/day columns and index those.  Or maybe by using [virtual columns](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_virtual_columns_preview) - but that's apparently an experimental feature, and I'm not so familiar with it.  Cheers!

Comment: @XavierHolt I have experienced that myself. Table scans when using date functions will absolutely kill performance. Even with as little as 1.2m rows, my I/O was through the roof. See here: http://blog.instaview.me/post/19221487428/performance-issues-with-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You could also add to your query to include a value that would be `1` if today was their birthday.  This makes it easier so in your PHP you don't have to make the comparison.

```
SELECT
    user_table.*,
    (MONTH(user_table.birth_date_column) = MONTH(now()) 
        AND DAY(user_table.birth_date_column) = DAY(now())) as birthday_today
FROM user_table
```

Other answers show query for getting those users whose birthday's are today

Answer (score 1):

Find people whose birthday has the same month and day as the current date:

```
SELECT * from people 
WHERE month(birthDate) = month(curdate()) 
AND dayofmonth(birthDate) = dayofmonth(curdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
where month(BirthDate) = month(curdate())
and day(BirthDate) = day(curdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Get User list whose birthday is today in mysql field datatype must be date 

$Toaday = '%'.date('m-d').'%';

$query = " select client_id,name,mobile_no from client where is_visible = 1 AND birth_date LIKE '$Toaday' ";
```

Answer (score -1):

To find employees' today birthday. we can use this

SELECT * 
FROM crm_employee
WHERE MONTH( dob ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) 
AND DAYOFMONTH( dob ) = DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE( ) )